# Books on probability more focused towards conditional probability and bayes theorem

Tags: probability, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am looking for a book on probability which is more focused towards things like conditional probability and baye's theorem.

My curriculum is limited only to only few concepts like independence, probability from basic counting, and has a lot of question from Bayes and conditional probability, so I was looking for a hard book, which provides a good explanation of these topics.

Most of the books that I searched on the web {Eg Introduction to Probability by Dimitri P. Bertsekas and John N. Tsitsiklis [Stuff in the first chapter is only in my syllabus and It is fine if the book you recommend has extra topics too, which don't diverge too much ]} , only talk briefly about these topics , and quickly move to the advanced part which is not in my Curriculum. ( So only basic Probability but good explanation/hard questions and no fancy theory [I'm in highschool so looking for that level] )

Please help

Comment: Most probability books have a chapter or two on these subjects. You may even find them in books subjected in "discrete math". A study in combinatorics and set theory could also aid you in probabitiy. It seems to me what youre going for here is a study on pure probability theory devoid of any reference to statistics and special distributions.

Answer (score 0):

The following book on probability might be useful

1. Probability and Conditional Expectation: Fundamentals for the Empirical Sciences (Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics) 1st Edition
   ISBN 978-1119243526

2.Introduction to Probability, Statistics, and Random Processes
978-0990637202

3.Bayesian Data Analysis (Chapman & Hall/CRC Texts in Statistical Science) 3rd Edition
978-1439840955